# Calculate mean by overlapping time intervals in one data frame with one datetime column in another data frame

Tags: pandas

How can I calculate mean by overlapping time intervals in one data frame with one datetime column in another data frame by grouping each name.

df1

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
              'time_start': ['2000-01-01 00:01:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:02:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:03:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:04:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:05:12'],
              'time_end': ['2000-01-01 00:01:18',
                            '2000-01-01 00:02:22',
                            '2000-01-01 00:03:24',
                            '2000-01-01 00:04:40',
                            '2000-01-01 00:05:14']})
 .assign(time_start = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['time_start']),
        time_end = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['time_end'])))
```

df2

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
              'time': ['2000-01-01 00:01:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:01:13',
                            '2000-01-01 00:01:14',
                            '2000-01-01 00:02:13',
                            '2000-01-01 00:02:20',
                            '2000-01-01 00:03:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:04:12',
                            '2000-01-01 00:04:30',
                            '2000-01-01 00:05:12'],
             'values': [10,20, 30, 40,50,60,70,80, 90]})
 .assign(time = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['time'])))
```

output should be

```
    name    time_start  time_end    values
0   a   2000-01-01 00:01:12 2000-01-01 00:01:18 20
1   a   2000-01-01 00:02:12 2000-01-01 00:02:22 45
2   a   2000-01-01 00:03:12 2000-01-01 00:03:24 60
3   a   2000-01-01 00:04:12 2000-01-01 00:04:40 75
4   b   2000-01-01 00:05:12 2000-01-01 00:05:14 90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join both DataFrames first and then test overlapping by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last aggregate `mean`:

*Solution working also for overlapping intervals.*

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='name')
df = (df[df['time'].between(df['time_start'], df['time_end'])]
          .groupby(['name','time_start','time_end'], as_index=False)['values']
          .mean())
print (df)
  name          time_start            time_end  values
0    a 2000-01-01 00:01:12 2000-01-01 00:01:18      20
1    a 2000-01-01 00:02:12 2000-01-01 00:02:22      45
2    a 2000-01-01 00:03:12 2000-01-01 00:03:24      60
3    a 2000-01-01 00:04:12 2000-01-01 00:04:40      75
4    b 2000-01-01 00:05:12 2000-01-01 00:05:14      90
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know the `between` function. Small correction - you could replace sum() to mean().

Answer (score 3):

Using a `merge` in this context is inefficient as it creates all combinations of rows per group (which would fill up the memory if the dataset is large).

For an efficient solution, use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
out = (pd
   .merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on='time', right_on='time_start', by='name')
   .query('time <= time_end')
   .groupby(['name', 'time_start', 'time_end'], as_index=False)['values'].mean()
)
```

*Note that `merge_asof` requires that the data is sorted by key (which is the case here for `time` and `time_start`). Else, first sort the data. The intervals should also be non-overlapping (again, the case here).*

If the data is not initially sorted:

```
out = (pd
   .merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='time'),
               df1.sort_values(by='time_start'),
               left_on='time', right_on='time_start', by='name')
   .query('time <= time_end')
   .groupby(['name', 'time_start', 'time_end'], as_index=False)['values'].mean()
)
```

Output:

```
  name          time_start            time_end  values
0    a 2000-01-01 00:01:12 2000-01-01 00:01:18    20.0
1    a 2000-01-01 00:02:12 2000-01-01 00:02:22    45.0
2    a 2000-01-01 00:03:12 2000-01-01 00:03:24    60.0
3    a 2000-01-01 00:04:12 2000-01-01 00:04:40    75.0
4    b 2000-01-01 00:05:12 2000-01-01 00:05:14    90.0
```

Comment: super cool! I should test which one of the above is faster.

Comment: @ferrelwill on small dataframes (like your example) a `merge` might be marginally faster, on larger ones `merge_asof` should be more efficient, on quite large ones, then `merge` should be much slower and eventually fill up the memory. Make sure to report the sizes and number of groups if you provide timings ;)

Comment: @sammywemmy which is indicated in my answer: "*The intervals should also be non-overlapping*", and is the case in the question ;)

Comment: Ahhh I missed that ... My bad